# Aws instance backup

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I would like to backup my AWS instance and RDS instance to my local machine. Is it possible to store the details in my local machine?

Thanks in advance

Regards,

Eleena Jose

Answer (score 0):

You can use create AMI of your instance as backup.

You can launch your instance from there and even share your image to other AWS accounts

The case is similar to RDS too

You can export all the databases from RDS and import into your local DB server

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Instead, create a snapshot of your volume. Amazon then stores it (somewhere) on S3 so that you can later create a volume out of it and attach it to your instances. Read more about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSSnapshots.html).

Also for your RDS, you should create snapshots as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshot.html).

There are some third party tools you can use to automate the backup process.